# MulterError: Unexpected field at wrappedFileFilter in node js, express, mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

The front end is React js, and the back is Node js, MySQL, express
I want to add multiple images together in the database, when i add one image it is success, but more than one no, it give me this error in the console:

```
POST http://localhost:3003/addeventimage 500 (Internal Server Error)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
```

And this error in the srever:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\AL-Madani\Desktop\ForGrad\NewProject\server\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19) at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AL-Madani\Desktop\ForGrad\NewProject\server\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:115:7) at Busboy.emit (events.js:400:28) at Busboy.emit
```

This my code in the front:

```
function AddEvent() {

    const [ActivityName, setActivityName] = useState("");
    const [Description, setDescription] = useState("");
    const [response, setresponse]= useState("")
    const [images, setimages] = useState([]);

    const setdatavalues= (event)=>{
            console.log('لقد قمت باختيار صورة/مجموعة صور')
            setimages(event.target.files) 
    }

    const AddNewEvent = () => {
        if(ActivityName === "" || Description === ""){
            setresponse('يرجى تعبئة الحقول الفارغة');
        } 
        Axios.post('http://localhost:3003/addevent', {
            ActivityName: ActivityName,
            Description: Description,
        }).then(()=>{
            Axios.get('http://localhost:3003/addnewevent')
            .then((respons) => {
                console.log(respons.data)
                const formData= new FormData()
                formData.append('ActivityName', ActivityName)
                for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
                    formData.append('image', images[i])
                }
                    console.log(respons.data[0].ActivityName)
                    console.log(ActivityName)
                        Axios.post('http://localhost:3003/addeventimage', formData)
                        .then(res => {               
                        console.log(res.data.msg);         
                    })
            })     
        })  
    }

    return (
        <div className="add">
            <br />

            <label><b>
                اسم الفعالية :
            </b></label>
            <input type="text" className="input" placeholder=" اسم الفعالية"
                onChange={(event) => {
                    setActivityName(event.target.value);
                }} />
            <br />
            <label><b>تفاصيل الفعالية :</b></label>
            <TextField className="input"
                label="أدخِل تفاصيل الفعالية"
                color="secondary"
                variant="outlined"
                multiline
                onChange={(event) => {
                    setDescription(event.target.value);
                }} />
            <br />
            <h4>{response}</h4> 
            <form>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label><b>
                    اختر صورة أو مجموعة صور:
            </b></label>
                    <input type="file" name="images" accept="image/*" 
                    multiple={true} className="form-control" 
                    id="customFile" onChange={setdatavalues}/>
                </div>
            </form>
            <br /> 
            <button className="addbtn" type="submit"
                onClick={AddNewEvent}>
                حفظ</button>

        </div>
    );
}
export default AddEvent;
```

And this is in the server:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./");
  },
  filename:  (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file)
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage
});
app.post("/addeventimage", upload.array("files", 100), (req, res, err) => {
  if (!req.files.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF)$/)) {
    res.send({ msg: 'Only image files (jpg, jpeg, png) are allowed!' })
  } else {
    const image= req.files;
    const ActivityName = req.body.ActivityName;
    db.query(
      INSERT INTO activityimages(ActivityName, image) VALUES (?, ?),
      [ActivityName, image], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err)
          res.send({
            msg: err
          });
        }
        else if (result) {
          res.send({
            data: result,
            msg: 'Your images have been inserted!'
          });
        }
      });
  }
})
```

What the error?

Comment: Provide full error log

Comment: MulterError: Unexpected field
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\AL-Madani\Desktop\ForGrad\NewProject\server\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AL-Madani\Desktop\ForGrad\NewProject\server\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:115:7)        
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at Busboy.emit

Comment: please put it in the question along with the short version of html form you are using to submit files, to better understand the problem.